# Java Faker Date Format (MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, faker

New at Java and trying to figure out how can set the random DOB I am generating to come back in the date format I need to send in my JSON requests.

My Java Faker code:

```
  public static String getRandomDOB() {
    Faker faker = new Faker();
    String dob = faker.date().birthday().toString();
    return dob.toString();
```

It is returning:
**Mon Oct 16 01:30:50 PDT 1978**

But I need it returning:
**(MM/DD/YYYY)**

Is there a simple, straightforward way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your are using the `Date` class. I recommend you don’t. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Date birthday = faker.date().birthday();

        LocalDate birthday_2 = Instant
                .ofEpochMilli(birthday.getTime())
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

Answer (score 3):

The `birthday()` method returns the standard `java.util.Date`, so you can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Faker faker = new Faker();
String dob = sdf.format(faker.date().birthday());
System.out.println(dob);
```